GA4: Why are my UTM link parameters showing on reports for pages they don't link to?
I created several UTM links for our ad campaigns for three different events in three different cities. Here's an example link I created using Google's link builder.
https://myurl.com/seminars/index.php?utm_source=dem_herald&utm_medium=calendar&utm_campaign=seminars_3novels_2024#education
I shortened them using TinyURL and tested them. The correct page is loading with the correct UTM parameters.
Even though I didn't use the default medium for these links, everything seemed to work fine until I started looking at separate unrelated pages which have nothing to do with the UTM linked pages.
I can tell they are showing for the wrong pages because when I use a filter to look at a single page (Dimension=Page path and screen class, Match Type=exactly matches, Value=/help/) the parameters for the /seminars/ page are showing in the report for the /help/ page.
The UTM parameters are showing up on most pages on the site in the Google reports even though they were linked to only the three event pages.
Could failing to use the default medium parameters have caused this problem?
Am I filtering incorrectly to look at a single page?
Are my UTM links incorrect?
I've tried looking at different non-UTM linked pages in different ways in GA4.
I've contacted Google Analytics support but they won't help because I'm not using Google Ads.
I've double checked my UTM links to make sure they're working correctly.
I've read a lot of web pages about GA4 and UTM links but nothing is addressing this problem.
